# Access MultiPage Items in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page in ASP .NET that uses a MultiPage, like this

[MultiPage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYcna.png)

The problem is that I need to access elements found in the second tab, but when I do the search, it returns null.

It does not allow me to access items in the tabs that are not currently selected.
For example there, being in "General", if I do a search for an element in "Security", the search returns null.

Here is the MultiPage code (I put it with fewer fields since they are quite a few and it would be very extensive).

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="clientDiv">
                    <mytab:TabStrip ID="tsHoriz" Style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold; FONT-SIZE: small" runat="server"
                        TargetID="mpHoriz">
                        <!-- TabStrip here -->
                    </mytab:TabStrip>

                    <mytab:MultiPage ID="mpHoriz"
                        Style="BORDER-TOP: 3px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 1px solid; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 1px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px solid;"
                        class="borde" runat="server">
                        <mytab:PageView>
                            <!--Elementos Pestaña 1 General-->
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_status" runat="server" CssClass="text_S10">
                                                        Status:</asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="left">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_status" runat="server" CssClass="text_S11"
                                                        Style="width: 150px;">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--- Seleccione ---</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="A">Active</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="C">Cancelado</asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </mytab:PageView>

                        <mytab:PageView>
                            <!--Elementos Pestaña 2 SEGURIDAD-->
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="white"
                                border="0" bordercolor="#cc0000" class="text_S10">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                                        <table class="text_S10" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" align="center" width="100%"
                                                    bgcolor="white" border="0" bordercolor="#cc0000"
                                                    cssclass="text_S11">
                                                    <tr id="__tr_accounts">
                                                        <table width="100%" id="__tbl_accounts"></table>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </mytab:PageView>
                        <mytab:PageView>
                            <!--Elementos Pestaña 4 CONTACT-->
                        </mytab:PageView>

                        <mytab:PageView>
                            <!--Elementos Pestaña 5 ESPECIALES-->
                        </mytab:PageView>
                    </mytab:MultiPage>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There positioned in "General" the following returns null

```
document.getElementById('__tbl_accounts');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you try the javascript block when the page load the first time? You can try right click on the page and select Inspect Element, and look if the id element is `__tbl_accounts`

Comment: And where is this code? `document.getElementById('__tbl_accounts');`.